# I need a measure to distinct count value in a month and when I choose total year it distinct count as well the value in the year in power bi

Tags: count, distinct

| Rig name | month. Year |
| --- | --- |
| Ad 32 | 8. |
| Ad 32 | 8. |
| Ad 20 | 8 |
| Ad 32 | 9. |
| Ad 20 | 9. |

I need my result when I filter month to be rig count 2 rig in month 8 and 2 rig in month 9

When I choose the whole year I want the rig count to be 2 not 4

I have a calendar table with relation to my main table date column I tried this measure

Rig count=
Countrows(summarize(tableeff,tableeff[year],tableeff[month],tableeff[rig name]

It get the rig count per month right 2 but the total year get 4